Using constexpr std::vector returned from consteval function in another consteval function
I have the following code and it works, but it is clunky due to double call to get_vec5 that is required.
namespace sr = std::ranges;
namespace sv = std::views;

template<int n>
consteval auto get_vec5() {
    return std::views::iota(0,n) | sv::filter([](const int i){return i%5 == 0;}) | sr::to<std::vector>();
}


consteval auto get_arr5() {
    constexpr int n = 42;
    auto v = get_vec5<n>();
    std::array<int, get_vec5<n>().size()> arr;
    sr::copy(v, arr.begin());
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto val = get_arr5();
    fmt::println("{}", val);
}

If I try to make v constexpr
    constexpr auto v = get_vec5<n>();

compiler is unhappy, and I can not use call v.size() to specify std::array size if v is not constexpr.
Is this intended behavior by C++ standard or quirk in compiler?
I am a bit confused that I can not get v.size() without invoking get_vec5 2 times. I would think if it is illegal it is illegal, and if it is not it should be a way for me to get it without invoking get_vec5 two times.

@fdan no it is exactly same question...   :)

You can use costexpr inplace_vector instead of get_vec5().
